# How to pass a state from BlocConsumer to FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am learning Retrofit and the flutter_bloc package. To do this, I first created a simple application with SetState that works as I intended. I am now rewriting it using the flutter_bloc package to better understand it. And I ran into the following problem.

This is the part of my code that is causing me questions.

```dart
class GetUsers extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetUsers({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<RetrofitBloc, RetrofitState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is RetrofitInitial) {
              return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                      context.read<RetrofitBloc>().add(UserRequestEvent());
                  },
                  child: Text("Get a list of users"),
                ),
              ),
          );
        }
        else if (state is RetrofitLoadInProgress) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (state is RetrofitLoadFailure) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error!"),
          );
        } else if (state is UserLoadSuccess) {

          final client = state.users;
          print('UserLoadSuccess');
          print('State.users is client: $client');
          return _buildBody(context);
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }

// build list view & manage states
  FutureBuilder<List<UserRequest>> _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    // RepoClass repoClass = RepoClass();
    // final client = repoClass.getUsersData();
    final client = state.users;
    return FutureBuilder<List<UserRequest>>(
      future: client,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final List<UserRequest>? users = snapshot.data;
          return _buildListView(context, users!);
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // build list view & its tile
  Widget _buildListView(BuildContext context, List<UserRequest> users) {
    return
      ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.account_box, color: Colors.green, size: 50,),
            title: Text(
              users[index].name, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            subtitle: Text(users[index].email),
          ),
        );
      }, itemCount: users.length,
      );
  }
}
```

I can't add

```dart
final client = state.users
```

to FutureBuilder.

This part of the code is commented out:

```dart
// RepoClass repoClass = RepoClass();
// final client = repoClass.getUsersData();
```

It is taken from my previous version and works. But I want FutureBuilder to take data from somewhere else. In particular, using BlocConsumer.

Now

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<UserRequest>> _buildBody(BuildContext context)
```

does not see my Bloc and, accordingly, its state.

How to fix it?

Comment: because you didn't pass the `state` to the function, use `_buildBody(BuildContext context, state UserLoadSuccess)`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right.

But the order in ```_buildBody(BuildContext context, state UserLoadSuccess)``` should be different. I mean not ```UserLoadSuccess state```, but ```UserLoadSuccess state```.

Then everything works great.

Thanks again.

Comment: LOL yes, I'm just used to golang